# Why is /usr/local/games after /usr/games in the default PATH?

Tags: environment-variables

The default value of the `PATH` environment variable in Ubuntu (13.10, at least) 
for an administrator (user in the `sudo` group) after logging in to the desktop environment is:

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

*/usr/local/sbin* and */usr/local/bin* appear **before** */usr/sbin* and */usr/bin*.
However, */usr/local/games* appears **after** */usr/games*.

Is there a reason for this? Or it's just a typo?

### More information

- Normal/administrator user's default `PATH` after logging with `su - user`:

  ```
  /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
  ```
- Normal/administrator user's default `PATH` after logging in a virtual console:

  ```
  /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
  ```
- Default `PATH` for the `root` user (after logging in with `sudo -i`; I haven't 
  tried enabling the root user and logging in through a virtual console):

  ```
  /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
  ```
- Content of */etc/environment*:

  ```
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
  ```
- Relevant line of */etc/sudoers*:

  ```
  Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
  ```
- Relevant lines of */etc/login.defs*:

  ```
  ENV_SUPATH      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
  ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
  ```

---

Repeating the main question: what's the reason for */usr/local/games* to appear 
after */usr/games*, instead of before, in the default `PATH`?

And a related question: from where does the value of `PATH` come from?
It seems */etc/environment* and */etc/login.defs* are both used in different situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't come up with any reason other than: it's a mistake.

From what I can see, `/usr/local/games` is a fairly late addition to `/etc/environment`.  A 12.04 machine of mine does not have it.

I was really struggling to find where `/etc/environment` comes from. Turns out it's not a file that's packaged, it's created at install time (I assume to prevent it harming existing configurations during upgrades). Thanks to [this answer on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85697/880), we can see that it's coming from `libpam-modules`'s `postinst` script.

```
# Add PATH to /etc/environment if it's not present there or in
# /etc/security/pam_env.conf
if [ "$1" = "configure" ] && dpkg --compare-versions "$2" lt 1.1.3-7ubuntu3; then
        if ! grep -qs ^PATH /etc/security/pam_env.conf; then
                if ! grep -qs ^PATH= /etc/environment; then
                        echo 'PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"' >> /etc/environment
                elif ! grep -qs "^PATH=.*/usr/local/games" /etc/environment; then
                        sed -i '/^PATH=/ s,:/usr/games,:/usr/games:/usr/local/games,g' /etc/environment
                fi
        fi
fi
```

So yeah, I'd suggest [reporting a bug against pam](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+filebug).

Comment: That's what I thought: a mistake/typo. Thank you for your answer! And thank you for finding out from where `/etc/environment` comes from, so now I/we can report a bug against a specific package! I'll report the bug and mark the accepted answer later today (in a few hours).

Comment: @BrunoNova My Debian has it in the correct order, so should be something specific to Ubuntu.

Comment: @Braiam That's odd because the postinst scripts for the Debian Sid version and the Ubuntu Trusty version are completely different (though the installed files are nigh-on the same). Where is Debian sourcing its copy of PATH in `/etc/environment`? Could you have a look around?

Comment: `grep -C 5 "/etc/environment" /var/lib/dpkg/info/*` should help.

Comment: Only `libpam-modules` touch the file (it doesn't create it) and is normally empty. The package that provides the path is called `base-files` which provides the `/etc/profiles` and profiles contains the path.

Comment: I reported the "bug": https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/1281802